# how to change default port in react app and define specific port to it

Tags: reactjs

React application got port 8080 which is not available to us at the moment.

How to change the default port number.

here is the error that is displayed when running the command npm start

**note: maybe this can be a different issue
, bit new to react development

````
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1517:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start: `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\harsha94\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-25T16_59_11_280Z-debug.log ```
````

Comment: did you try `yarn start`? if the default port is taken, will prompt you if you want to run on a different port.

Comment: Even `npm start` prompts to use other port if one port is already used.

Answer (score 4):

- Add below line in your package.json file

  "scripts": { "start": "PORT=5600 react-scripts start",
- npm install
- npm start

Comment: Thank you. This works. Changing 'proxy' in package.json does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok cool noted the problem 'It is a conflicted port in webpack.config.js.'

which we can easily change by using adding port to devServer with specific port {  port: 8006 } like below.

```
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 8006, // <--- Add this line and choose your own port number
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
```

Comment: See my answer below... If you use those versions at the very least you'll get security vulnerability warnings...

Answer (score 0):

From the error, more specifically this line: `npm ERR! redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start: node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`

It looks like you're not using `create-react-app` but (from a google search) this repo: `https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter`

Considering the versions in `package.json` (for example, it's using `"webpack": "^1.12.9"` and the current version is `4.32.2`) I would recommend that you use: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/ instead...

But if you insist on using it that repo then add the port to your `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 9000 // add port here...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In package.json

"start": "npm run build && serve -s build -l 5000"

This shall work if you use serve